# Lua error: string expected, got nil

Tags: function, console, lua, null

I need help with my scripts.
I tried nearly everything, but I can't figure it out what the problem is.
I want `look.lua` to check if `str = str.."\nIt's "..getPokemonAge(thing.uid).." old."`
Returns with nil, then ignores it and goes on with the script.

This is the error I get on console:

```
[04/12/2012 20:43:42] [Error - CreatureScript Interface] 
[04/12/2012 20:43:42] data/creaturescripts/scripts/look.lua:onLook
[04/12/2012 20:43:42] Description: 
[04/12/2012 20:43:42] data/lib/011-string.lua:16: bad argument #1 to 'find' (string expected, got nil)
[04/12/2012 20:43:42] stack traceback:
[04/12/2012 20:43:42]   [C]: in function 'find'
[04/12/2012 20:43:42]   data/lib/011-string.lua:16: in function '(for generator)'
[04/12/2012 20:43:42]   data/lib/011-string.lua:16: in function 'explode'
[04/12/2012 20:43:42]   data/lib/age system.lua:2: in function 'getPokemonYears'
[04/12/2012 20:43:42]   data/lib/age system.lua:42: in function 'getPokemonAge'
[04/12/2012 20:43:42]   data/creaturescripts/scripts/look.lua:32: in function <data/creaturescripts/scripts/look.lua:1>
```

011-string.lua

```
local i, pos, tmp, t = 0, 1, "", {}
        for s, e in function() return string.find(str, sep, pos) end do
            tmp = str:sub(pos, s - 1):trim()
            table.insert(t, tmp)
            pos = e + 1

            i = i + 1

        end
```

look.lua

```
str = str.."\nIt's "..getPokemonAge(thing.uid).." old."
```

age system.lua

```
function getPokemonYears(pokeball)
local data = string.explode(getItemAttribute(pokeball, "pokeballinfo"), "/")
-- data[1] = dia, data[2] = mes, data[3] = ano
local yearnow = math.floor(tonumber(os.date("%Y")))
local monthnow = math.floor(tonumber(os.date("%m")))
local daynow = math.floor(tonumber(os.date("%d")))
local ano = math.floor(tonumber(data[3]))
local mes = math.floor(tonumber(data[2]))
local dia = math.floor(tonumber(data[1]))
local years = 0
if yearnow == ano then years = monthnow-mes end
if yearnow > ano then years = (12-mes) + monthnow end
return years
end

function getPokemonMonths(pokeball)
local data = string.explode(getItemAttribute(pokeball, "pokeballinfo"), "/")
local yearnow = math.floor(tonumber(os.date("%Y")))
local monthnow = math.floor(tonumber(os.date("%m")))
local daynow = math.floor(tonumber(os.date("%d")))
local ano = math.floor(tonumber(data[3]))
local mes = math.floor(tonumber(data[2]))
local dia = math.floor(tonumber(data[1]))

if (yearnow == ano) and (monthnow==mes) and (daynow<dia+2.5) then months = 0 end
if (yearnow == ano) and (monthnow==mes) and (daynow>dia+2.5) then months = (daynow-dia)/2.5 end
if (yearnow == ano) and (monthnow>mes) then months = math.floor((30-dia)/2.5) + daynow/2.5 end
if (yearnow > ano) then
days = math.floor(monthnow*30+daynow)
months = math.floor(days/2.5)
end
if tostring(months):len() > 3 then months2 = tonumber(string.sub(tostring(months), 1, 3))
else months2 = months end
return months
end


function getPokemonAge(pokeball)
return ""..getPokemonYears(pokeball).." year, "..getPokemonMonths(pokeball).." months"
end
```

Comment: It sounds like `getItemAttribute(pokeball, "pokeballinfo")` is returning `nil`.

Comment: but how to if returning nil to just ignore and proceed if not retirning nil then vieuw

Comment: but how to if returning nil to just ignore and proceed so when not nil then 
return ""..getPokemonYears(pokeball).." year, "..getPokemonMonths(pokeball).." months"
and when its returning nil then not do
str = str.."\nIt's "..getPokemonAge(thing.uid).." old."

Comment: There's way too much code, parse the useless code out and you'll get much more answers.

Comment: how are you requir'ing in the various files you've created?

Comment: Can you include some sample data?

Comment: Your pokeball seems to have the "pokeballinfo" attribute missed.

Comment: You need to indent your code for it to be readable.  You to describe which files are being loaded in what order.  You to indicate what the line numbers are.  It's almost impossible to figure out what your code is even supposed to be doing, because you've merely provided little isolated snippets.

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally understand your question, so I will rephrase how I understand it and you can tell whether that was what you wanted.

As I understand it you know that your function `getPokemonAge` sometimes causes an error. Several others pointed out that this error is from `getItemAttribute(pokeball, "pokeballinfo")` returning `nil`.

Now I think you want the program to return the text if a text was produced, but to ignore any error that might occur and return `nil` in case of error.

This can be done with pcall ([look here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-pcall)).

In my partial rewrite of your getPokemonAge-Function I call `getPokemonAgeInternal` (which is your orginal function) with pcall. Then I just check the result and return `nil` on error.

```
function getPokemonAgeInternal(pokeball)

    return ""..getPokemonYears(pokeball).." year, "..getPokemonMonths(pokeball).." months"
end

function getPokenmonAge(pokeball)
    success, value = pcall( getPokemonAgeInternal, pokeball )
    if ( success )
    then
        return value
    else
        return nil
    end
end
```

You can apply similar code to your `getPokemonYears`-Function instead if you want to protect that against errors.

If your error always comes from `getItemAttribute(pokeball, "pokeballinfo")` being `nil` you should not use pcall, but instead just check that condition and return nil if `getItemAttribute(pokeball, "pokeballinfo") == nil`.